# is there a similar way to make this excel-vba code to work on access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I add a automatically number depends on my last row?

On Excel I can take as a reference this code:

```
Lastentry = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Help1 = Replace(Range("B" & Last_entry).Value, "B-AK", "")
Boxnummer.Value = "B-AK" & (CInt(Help1) + 1)
```

But on my Access database I dont know how to take raws as a reference. I looked on the internet after some solutions but I couldnt find usefull information because actually I havent got good access-skills..

Comment: Fixed code formatting, improved question and corrected spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on what you're trying to achieve. There are a number of different ways to get the record count.

> 1) DCount function:

```
Dim count_ As Long
    count_ = DCount("*","TableName")
```

> 2) Recordset.RecordCount property:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableName")
    rs.MoveLast

count_ = rs.RecordCount
```

> 3) Control.ControlSource property:

```
TextBox.ControlSource = "=Count(*)"
```

**Edit:**

In this case you need the [DLookup](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) function. Have a look at the attached link to understand more about the `DLookup` function, but in a few words it means:

*Give me the last value in "ColumnName" which is located in "TableName".*

```
Dim ref As String
    ref = "B-AK" & Format(Date, "yy") & _
          DLookup("ColumnName", "TableName", "ID=" & DMax("ID", "TableName")) 
         'Change "ColumnName", "TableName" and "ID" to their actual names.
```

Comment: i am trying to give my new data a autonumber value based on the last inserted row on my table. 

the new autonumber should always include the letters "B-AK" the date "yy" and the "count of the rows"

Comment: i used the code as follows:

Dim Count As Long
Count = DCount("*", "TableName")
Me.Textbox.Value = "B-AK" & Format(Date, "yy") & Count

Is there an opportunity to take the value in the last row as a reference instead of DCount function?

Comment: The function DCount counts the number of rows, but my question was is there any other oppurtinity to take the last value in a column as a reference. 

I tried the code:

Me!Textbox = "B-AK" & Format(Date, "yy",2,2) & DMax("Column", "TableName") +1 

This code didnt work because the column doenst contain only a number, it also contains  three letters "B-AK"